# What did GDB do when set endian big

Tags: gdb, endianness

Generally, we can change the endianness when debuging, but is there someone knows what does gdb do when we running a command as
(gdb) set endian big
or
(gdb) set endian small

I have the gdb sources in hand, but haven't found where to refer yet.

Comment: Note that this setting seems to be partly broken, at least in recent GDB.  It corrupts register values.  See an example on [Flipping endianness in gdb?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63552401)

Answer (score 1):

See gdb/arch-utils.c:set_endian.  It tries to select a new gdbarch that matches the specified endianness, via gdbarch_update_p.